# automatically check in all changes in TFS

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I am new to TFS (have used Source-Safe and Perforce in the past) and am working on a large project. Over the past few days I have changed several files in multiple locations.

Is there an option in TFS to select all of the files that I have changed, and added, and check them all in?

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and TFS 2012.

**NOTE :** I have not explicitly checked these files out, I have just begun editing.

Comment: When you start editing, the files are automatically checked out. No explicit check-out command is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select that folder in TFS explorer and right click. you will see the option "Checkin Pending changes.."

Answer (score 1):

In the team explorer open up the source control tab, then right click on the route folder and select Check in Pending Changes.

This will check in all the files over all the solutions/projects that you have underneath the root.  Repeat the process for any other team collections you have used.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in the whole project or solution by right clicking the solution name from the solution explorer window and click Check in pending changes.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, open the Pending Changes window to view all changes that are waiting to be checked in.  If you are using a single workspace, you will see all your pending changes across all solutions.

**For Visual Studio 2012 and 2010:**

From menu, select **"View > Other Windows > Pending Changes"**.